# Javascript for Slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am attempting to create a slideshow, where each slide is desplayed for an interval of 2000 milliseconds, yet, I can not get the second slide to show... I have included My Javascript and CSS below and any help or simple modifications that you think would help would be much appreciated. I believe it is a simple fix, but I just need another pair of eyes to help with this issue...

```css
body{
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* FOR SLIDES */

/*
essential styles:
these make the slideshow work
*/
#slides{
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.slide{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;

 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing{
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 2;
}



/*
non-essential styles:
just for appearance; change whatever you want
*/

.slide{
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(1){
 background: url(Slide0.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(2){
 background: url(Slide1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(3){
 background: url(Slide2.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(4){
 background: url(Slide3.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(5){
 background: url(Slide4.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- CSS -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
      <title>Widget1.0</title>
      <!-- JS!!! -->
      <script>
      var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
      var currentSlide = 0;
      var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

      function nextSlide(){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
      }

      var playing = true;
      var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

      function pauseSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
        playing = false;
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
      }

      function playSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
        playing = true;
        slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
      }

      pauseButton.onclick = function(){
        if(playing){ pauseSlideshow(); }
        else{ playSlideshow(); }
      };
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide showing" id="slide1">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide2">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide3">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide4">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide5">Slide 5</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your javascript on DOM ready event or move the function after the element has been rendered, ie: just above the `</body>` tag

```css
body{
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* FOR SLIDES */

/*
essential styles:
these make the slideshow work
*/
#slides{
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.slide{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;

 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing{
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 2;
}



/*
non-essential styles:
just for appearance; change whatever you want
*/

.slide{
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(1){
 background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(2){
 background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(3){
 background-color: green;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(4){
 background-color: magenta;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(5){
 background-color: orange;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#pause
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- CSS -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
      <title>Widget1.0</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide showing" id="slide1">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide2">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide3">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide4">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide5">Slide 5</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
      <!-- JS!!! -->
      <script>
      var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
      var currentSlide = 0;
      var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

      function nextSlide(){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
      }

      var playing = true;
      var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

      function pauseSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
        playing = false;
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
      }

      function playSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
        playing = true;
        slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
      }

      pauseButton.onclick = function(){
        if(playing){ pauseSlideshow(); }
        else{ playSlideshow(); }
      };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just code execution. You should set your vars, register the click listener and start the setinterval on load of the page (or even better use jquery and use the ready event

1. I added an init function that runs on body.onload which sets your
   global vars, your click listener, and starts the setinterval
2. I commented out where you set your global vars at the top and just declared them as they are now set in init()

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- CSS -->

      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> -->
      <title>Widget1.0</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
   body{
     background: white;
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   /* FOR SLIDES */

   /*
   essential styles:
   these make the slideshow work
   */
   #slides{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
   }

   .slide{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
   }

   .showing{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
   }



   /*
   non-essential styles:
   just for appearance; change whatever you want
   */

   .slide{
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
   }

   .slide:nth-of-type(1){
    background: url(http://placehold.it/720x246?text=Slide0.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
   .slide:nth-of-type(2){
    background: url(http://placehold.it/720x246?text=Slide1.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
   .slide:nth-of-type(3){
    background: url(http://placehold.it/720x246?text=Slide2.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
   .slide:nth-of-type(4){
    background: url(http://placehold.it/720x246?text=Slide3.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
   .slide:nth-of-type(5){
    background: url(http://placehold.it/720x246?text=Slide4.png) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
      </style>
      <!-- JS!!! -->
      <script>
      var slides;// = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
      var currentSlide;// = 0;
      var slideInterval;// = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

      function nextSlide(){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
      }

      var playing;// = true;
      var pauseButton;// = document.getElementById('pause');

      function pauseSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
        playing = false;
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
      }

      function playSlideshow(){
        pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
        playing = true;
        slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
      }

      function init()
      {
       playing = true;
       pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
       slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
       currentSlide = 0;
       slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
       pauseButton.onclick = function(){
        if(playing){ pauseSlideshow(); }
         else{ playSlideshow(); }
       };
      }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="init()">
      <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide showing" id="slide1">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide2">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide3">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide4">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="slide" id="slide5">Slide 5</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
   </body>
</html>
```